# AWS Route 53 Domain Point To Github Pages

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-pages, amazon-route53

I am new to working with AWS and route 53 so any help is appreciated.

I have created an organization on GitHub, and then created a simple repository for a static site to display with Github pages. this is working as expected and I can see the static site at  the URL generated by Github (something like: `https://<githubOrgName>.github.io/<repoName>/`)

I got a domain from AWS and now I'm trying to set it up so the apex domain (e.g. "my-domain.com") points to the Github pages site.

I followed the instructions found at: https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/about-custom-domains-and-github-pages ... but it doesn't seem to be working.

I am trying to make it so that the apex domain points to the repository Github page. something like:

`https://my-domain.com -> https://<githubOrgName>.github.io/<repoName>/`

... but this only shows a blank screen when I go to the root domain ("my-domain.com"). I have also tried to go to `https://my-domain.com/<repoName>/`... but this shows me a Github 404 page (so it seems to be correctly forwarding something to Github):

[image]

my AWS route 53 configuration is similar to the following (i have tried to remove sensitive details):

[image]

can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong? I am new to working with domains so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using Route53 alone won't help you there, because your target URL contains a URL path i.e. `/<repoName>/`.

> DNS is a name resolution system and knows nothing about HTTP

Furthermore, the origin server (`github.io`) might be running a reverse proxy which might be parsing the request headers, among which is the `Host` header. You browser automatically sets this header to the url you feed it. Eventually, you send it the wrong header (i.e. https://my-domain.com/), which Github cannot process. You can explicitly set this header (e.g. via `curl`) to what Github is expecting, but I believe it's not what you and your users would like.

Instead, you could try using layer 7 redirects (301/302) with the help of `Lambda@Edge` (provided by AWS CloudFront). I have created a simple [solution](https://github.com/maslick/redirector) using the Serverless framework, which does the following redirects:

```
https://maslick.tech     ->  https://github.com/maslick
https://maslick.tech/cv  ->  https://www.linkedin.com/in/maslick/
https://maslick.tech/qa  ->  https://stackoverflow.com/users/2996867/maslick
https://maslick.tech/ig  ->  https://www.instagram.com/maslick/
```

But you can customize it by adjusting `handler.js` according to your needs. You might also need to create a free TLS certificate using AWS Certificate Manager in the `us-east-1` region and attach it to your CloudFront distribution. But this is optional.

`Lambda@Edge` will give low latencies, since your redirects will be served from CloudFront's edge locations across the globe.

Answer (score 0):

How I got it to work was:

1. Set a CNAME record from example.org to `<USERNAME>/github.io.` in the Route 53 console
2. Set Custom domain to example.org in the Github Pages settings for `github.com/<USERNAME>/<REPO>`

*Note: You shouldn't be setting the CNAME record to `<USERNAME>/github.io/<REPO>`*

Source: https://deanattali.com/blog/multiple-github-pages-domains/

Comment: This doesn't address the AWS Route 53 Apex Record issue that disallows CNAME records for the domain.

Comment: Is there an extra '.' here - should it be <USERNAME>/github.io ?

Comment: to do it the apex domain way, hit the wizard (i know, i know) and tell it you want a geodistributed record.  suddenly you're allowed to make ALIAS records, which allow you to point at whatever distribution is appropriate on the fly.