# AWS API Gateway -> Lambda -> Github Pages

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to point a domain to Github pages site.

I am very new to working with domains and AWS services so I am finding it difficult to troubleshoot issues.

I have created an AWS ApiGateway that points to a lambda function which I would like to use to serve the content from Github pages, but currently, it is giving me the error:

```
{"message":"Internal Server Error"}
```

so when trying to fix this issue, I found instructions to make it log additional debug information. (instructions found at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-troubleshooting-lambda.html)

this is telling me that my configuration for the lambda function is incorrect.

```
The response from the Lambda function doesn't match the format that API Gateway expects. Lambda body contains the wrong type for field "headers"
```

I don't know what is expected so I don't know what needs to be changed... my entire lambda function is configured as:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    let domain = 'https://github-org-name.github.io/my-repo-with-gh-pages/';

    return {
        statusCode: '301',
        statusDescription: 'Moved Permanently',
        headers: {
          'location': [{
            key: 'Location',
            value: domain,
          }],
          'cache-control': [{
            key: 'Cache-Control',
            value: "max-age=3600"
          }]
        },
    }
};
```

I am completely new to using AWS services, so I don't know if anything else needs to be configured. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not just point the domain directly to GitHub Pages? Why use AWS services for this at all?

Comment: can you suggest how?... my main difficulty is because of being unfamiliar with AWS services. I thought doing it this way would enable me to also have the domain be able to also route to other static sites if needed. please see my previous attempt to point the domain directly to the Github page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70049275/aws-route-53-domain-point-to-github-pages

Comment: If you're doing path routing to different static sites I would use a CDN like CloudFront or Cloudflare (I recommend Cloudflare). API Gateway is overkill for this, and you aren't serving an API at all, so it's really not the right tool.

Answer (score 0):

The values in your headers dict must be strings, e.g:

```
{
    "cookies" : ["cookie1", "cookie2"],
    "isBase64Encoded": true|false,
    "statusCode": httpStatusCode,
    "headers": { "headername": "headervalue", ... },
    "body": "Hello from Lambda!"
}
```

See the bottom of this page:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.html